# VBA UDF to split string array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I've written this function which works, now I want to be able to call it as a worksheet function as in the pics, any guidance would be welcome:

There are two parts to the array separated by a semi-colon.

```
Function CellToRange(strDelimiter As String, Optional strColDelimiter As String) As String

    On Error GoTo CellToRange_Error

    Dim rnSource, rnDest As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Orig As Variant
    Dim txt As String
    Dim intPos As Integer

    Set rnSource = Range("F16")
    Set rnDest = Range("D21")

    txt = rnSource
    Orig = Split(txt, strDelimiter)
    intPos = InStr(1, txt, strColDelimiter) / 2

    For i = 0 To intPos - 1
        If i = intPos - 1 Then
            rnDest.Offset(i).Value = Mid(Orig(i), 1, InStr(1, Orig(i), strColDelimiter) - 1)
        Else
            rnDest.Offset(i).Value = Orig(i)
        End If
    Next i

    For i = intPos - 1 To UBound(Orig)
        If i = intPos - 1 Then
            rnDest.Offset(i - (intPos - 1), 1).Value = Mid(Orig(i), InStr(1, Orig(i), strColDelimiter) + 1, Len(Orig(i)))
        Else
            rnDest.Offset(i - (intPos - 1), 1).Value = Orig(i)
        End If
    Next i

    On Error GoTo 0

    Exit Function

CellToRange_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CellToRange of Function Functions"

End Function
```

[image: How I'd like to call the function]

[image: Desired outcome]

Comment: The function does not return a value. A UDF should return a value to the cell in which it is entered, not alter cells around it.

Comment: This is where I'm stuck. Not done this before... can you see what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I understand what you're saying now :-) Maybe I can't call it as a worksheet function. BUT when I add the ranges as arguments, the code doesn't work and I can't figure out why...

Comment: What's it meant to do?  I enter `a,b,c,d,e,f` in cell F16 with a comma delimiter and no optional strColDelimiter and it throws an error at `Mid(Orig(i)....` in your second `For...Next` loop because i = -1.  Your attached pictures aren't showing on my PC so can't see desired outcome.

Comment: A User Defined Function that you wish to enter in a cell has it's input parameters and a return value (and only 1 return value). This return value ends up in the cell in which the UDF is entered. What you're trying to do is not possible. During the execution of the UDF you **can not alter cells**, you'll need a regular macro for this purpose.

Comment: Darren Bartrup-Cook, if you try a,b,c;d,e,f (semi-colon between c and d)  where the optional strColDelimiter is ";" (semi-colon) you'll see the result, but it doesn't seem to work when I assign rnSource and rnDest as arguments

Answer (score 0):

Here be dragons. Haven't tryed this before and I hope I understood you right.
At this moment it takes source cell, where numbers are located, and destination cell, which is top left cell of output table. Currently delimiters are "," and ";" for lines and columns respectively.
You can modify sub to suit your needs from this point.

```
Public Function mytest(src, dest)
    dest.Parent.Evaluate "test(" & src.Address(False, False) & ", " & dest.Address(False, False) & ")"
    mytest = "wut"
End Function

Sub test(src As Range, dest As Range)
    Dim chr, rows, cols
    rows = 0
    cols = 0
    For chr = 1 To Len(src.Value)
        Select Case Mid(src.Value, chr, 1)
            Case ","
                rows = rows + 1
            Case ";"
                cols = cols + 1
                rows = 0
            Case Else
                Cells(dest.Row + rows, dest.Column + cols).Value = Cells(dest.Row + rows, dest.Column + cols).Value & Mid(src.Value, chr, 1)
        End Select
    Next chr
End Sub
```

P.S. I might be wrong but this will be the closest as you can get with modifying cells with UDF.
P.P.S. Welp, my Function actualy returns surprising results, I'll try to fix it asap, but mb you have other suggestions.