# Excel UDF doubles value of the evaluated SUB

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

**1.** I was trying to answer [VBA UDF to split string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45503075/vba-udf-to-split-string-array/45561377#45561377) and got an unpleasant results during computing my UDF.

```
Public Function mytest(src, dest)
    dest.Parent.Evaluate "test(" & src.Address(False, False) & ", " & dest.Address(False, False) & ")"
    mytest = "wut"
End Function

Sub test(src As Range, dest As Range)
    Dim chr, rows, cols
    rows = 0
    cols = 0
    For chr = 1 To Len(src.Value)
        Select Case Mid(src.Value, chr, 1)
            Case ","
            rows = rows + 1
            Case ";"
            cols = cols + 1
            rows = 0
            Case Else
            Cells(dest.Row + rows, dest.Column + cols).Value = Cells(dest.Row + rows, dest.Column + cols).Value & Mid(src.Value, chr, 1) '
        End Select
    Next chr
End Sub
```

**Expected results:**
[image]
**Formula results:**
[image]
Can someone explain why does it double Value of the cell?
When I debugged **test** using

```
Sub ffs()
    Call test(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, 1))
End Sub
```

I got expected results, so I guess the problem is not in the **test** Sub?..

**2.** Whenever I try to add more parameters to Function and Sub (for example delimiters) Function doesn't Evaluate Sub at all

```
Public Function CellToRange(src, dest, DelimL, DelimC)
    dest.Parent.Evaluate "test(" & src.Address(False, False) & ", " & dest.Address(False, False) & ", " & DelimL & ", " & DelimC & ")"
    CellToRange = "wut"
End Function

Sub CTR(src As Range, dest As Range, Delim1, Delim2)
    Dim chr, rows, cols
    rows = 0
    cols = 0
    For chr = 1 To Len(src.Value)
        Select Case Mid(src.Value, chr, 1)
            Case Delim1
            rows = rows + 1
            Case Delim2
            cols = cols + 1
            rows = 0
            Case Else
            Cells(dest.Row + rows, dest.Column + cols).Value = Cells(dest.Row + rows, dest.Column + cols).Value & Mid(src.Value, chr, 1) '
        End Select
    Next chr
End Sub
```

Please help ._. and thanks in advance.
**Solution:**
Thanks Billy and Charles Williams.
Change

```
dest.Parent.Evaluate "CTR(" & src.Address(False, False) & ", " & dest.Address(False, False) & ", " & DelimL & ", " & DelimC & ")"
```

To

```
dest.Parent.Evaluate "0+CTR(" & src.Address(False, False) & ", " & dest.Address(False, False) & ", " & DelimL & ", " & DelimC & ")"
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop VBA Evaluate from calling target function twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611929/stop-vba-evaluate-from-calling-target-function-twice)

Comment: @ Billy That.. actualy solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with the `Worksheet.Evaluate` method which is being used to get round the restriction that a UDF is not allowed to modify the worksheet structure.

Consider this code

```
Option Explicit

Public Function dummyudf() As String
    Debug.Print "Calling Evaluate method"
    ActiveSheet.Evaluate "testsub()"
    Debug.Print "Returning From Evaluate method"
    dummyudf = "done"
End Function

Sub testsub()
    Debug.Print "testsub running"
End Sub

Sub testmacro()
    Dim s As String
    Debug.Print "testmacro running"
    s = dummyudf
End Sub
```

The UDF `dummyudf()` uses the `Evaluate` method to `invoke` the `Sub` called `testsub()`. These are analagous to `mytest` and `test` in part 1. of the OP and to `CellToRange` and `CTR` in part 2 but are stripped down to the bare minimum.

`testsub()` can also be invoked directly as a macro. A second macro `testmacro` invokes `dummyudf` as a function in VBA.

The following output was obtained from the Immediate Window:

[image: Output from Immediate Window]

As can be seen

- when invoked as a macro: `testsub()` behaves as expected
- when `dummyudf()` is invoked as a UDF on the worksheet (for example by adding the formula `=dummyudf()` to cell `A1` the `Evaluate` method appears to call `testsub()` twice
- when `dummyudf()` is invoked as a function in VBA by running `testmacro()` as a macro the `Evaluate` method appears to call `testsub()` twice.

The documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-evaluate-method-excel) suggests that the *Name* argument of the `Worksheet.Evaluate` method should be the name of an object, so it is a bit surprising that it is possible supply the name of a `Sub`. That it also seems to call any such `Sub` twice, is even more surprising but does underline the advice given in YowE3K's answer about not using this hack in a UDF. I'd go further: don't use `Worksheet.Evaluate` with any `Sub`.

Comment: I'm sorry I had to do that, curiosity killed the cat.

Answer (score 1):

1) <s>It evaluates once when the formula is triggered, and again when cell A3 is updated by the function (as it is one of the cells the formula is dependent on).</s>

2a) You are calling the wrong subroutine (`test` instead of `CTR`)

2b) You need to call your second function using something like

```
=CellToRange(A1;A3;""",""";""";""")
```

or else change the line in your code calling CTR to be

```
dest.Parent.Evaluate "CTR(" & src.Address(False, False) & ", " & dest.Address(False, False) & ", """ & DelimL & """, """ & DelimC & """)"
```

3) I strongly recommend that you do not use this sort of hack to get a UDF to update cells other than the one containing the function.

Comment: @ YowE3k 1) Should not the function be called twice to evaluate twice? When I toggle breakpoint at start of the function and compute on a sheet, I see that it only runs 1 time. Sorry, if I understand incorrectly. 2a) Ops! ^^' 2b) Did it 3) I only did it for the sake of improving

Comment: @ YowE3K 2a) Hm, it didnt work out 2b) Changed the line, now it copies **src** `cell` to **dest** `cell` (hmmm) Also, when I computed **CellToRange** it didnt evaluate twice as **my test**

Comment: @AntiDrondert 1) Yes, it looks like I was mistaken.  Stepping through the code shows the evaluate executing once, and the sheet not being updated at all until the function is finished.  And I tried offsetting the location at which it writes, so that it wasn't writing to the referred to cell, and it still duplicates things.  2b) Both methods work OK for me (apart from the duplication)

Comment: 2b) Forgot yet another double quote (so much pain, nearly as bad as parentheses in Lisp) now it works fine.. except for duplication. Maybe there is a reason for it? Can Evaluate act as "calling" Sub twice? I'm not familiar with this method.